# About proof of a theorem from the Topology book by Munkres

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

My question regards to the theorem "Given a nonvanishing vector field on $B^{2}$, there is a point on $S^1$ where the vector is pointed directly inward ''and'' a point where the vector points directly outward given in p.350 from the second edition of the Topology book by Munkres. I presume that one has to prove the existence of such points in $S^{1}$ with vectors directing directly inward and outward for the same vector field $(x,v(x))$. Using previous results, Munkres shows the existence of a point in $S^{1}$ where the vector should point directly inward for the given vector field $(x,v(x))$. Later in the proof, the existence of a point at which the vector points outward was shown using the vector field $(x,-v(x))$ which is different from the vector field $(x,v(x))$. Am I missing anything? Or the ''and'' in the statement should be replaced by an ''or''?

Comment: I don't have the text but I'd imagine if shown with $-v$ "inward", the proof should be equivalent to showing with $+v$ "outward"

Comment: @David P Putting a minus in front would change the vector field. Shouldn't one show both the existences (inward and outward) using the same vector field?

Comment: Yes, but the Point is that flipping the sign makes any inward pointing Vector an outward pointing for the original

Comment: @AlexanderSchmeding That's fine. But have a look at the statement of the theorem. I've put "and" inside quotation in my question. If it's an "or", I'm perfectly fine with the statement. If it's "and", then it means that the same vector field should give the inward and outward pointing vectors.

Comment: If field $(x,v(x))$ has an inward pointing vector and field$ (x, -v(x))$ has an inward pointing vector, then the latter implies that $(x,v(x))$ has an outward pointing vector (as well as the inward pointing one found first).

Comment: Yes, the proof should Go as follows (though without having munkres book here its hard to tell): prove existence of an inward pointing Vector both for V and -V (ignoring now the Basepoint, as only the Vector part is Essential).  Thus as a consequence V Will have both an inward and outward pointing value.

Comment: @Hasib, The proof is perfectly alright. When we are working with the vector field, you agree that we get a point on $S^1$ where the vector field directed inwards, now the same proof works with the vector field $(x,-v(x))$ ie. there exists a point where the -ve vector field directed inwards, hence the original vector field directed outwards.The theorem is  also true for $B^n.$

Comment: @Dey Thanks! I noticed it earlier.